# loading image from local disk to html

Tags: html, node.js

I have to upload an image onto my HTML page from my local disk, which I know now is not possible because of the security reasons and the same origin policies.

1.) My image 'loadingimage.jpg' is at the same location as my .html page.
I did try relative paths like

```
<style>
body {
background-image: url("/loadingimage.jpeg");
}
</style>
```

and it gives me error like

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  
http://10.2.9.208:8081/loadingimage.jpg
```

I do not get this error when I open files directly, only when I am using node js express to serve this html file from my disk. I have this code in my node js

```
app.get('/abt', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../startpage.html'));
});
```

Please do not downvote this question as a duplicate as I have gone through all the links and have not been able to find a solution.So, I am reposting it. Can this be done without conversion to base64 codes? What do I do?

2.)But even if I somehow manage to display it on my browser, I want all the clients browsing my webpage to be able to see it, like suppose a WELCOME image. How do I make it possible?

I am not allowed to use any image hosting servers on the web. Can I do something like accessing the client PC and storing the image locally there, using it and then deleting it when the page is closed?.

I have a server machine running in the background, Is it in any way possible to store these images on the server and then retrieve it and display it on the client PC?

EDIT 1:
I tried using this

```
 <img class="logo" src="http://10.2.9.208:8081/loadingimage.jpg" alt="My_Logo">
```

This now, not only gives me the same error, but also displays a broken image.

the fiddle for this : https://jsfiddle.net/SuchitraIyer/sno3j98w/

Comment: Is your file name is correct ( spelling and extension) ?

Comment: where is your css  in which you call image?

Comment: yes. They are all perfect

Comment: @mukesh, I have edited the code

Comment: try to open your image in browser using absolute path.

Comment: They are working fine now directly, only node js express gives an error

Comment: are you using external css?

Comment: @Nitin, it is not external, it is a part of my HTML file only.

Comment: access your image path same as  your html page like '../../loadingimage.jpg'

Comment: your relative path is not your image location directory

Comment: Try changing nodejs express to serve all static files:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084360/using-node-js-as-a-simple-web-server

Comment: @RahulR, Hi, if my express can server startpage.html, why will it not serve image.html placed at the same location?

Comment: @SuchitraIyer, It can, if you do so, I am not sure about syntax to be used, but quick googling should help.

Comment: Hi, My express has been configured fine and so, my .html pages are being called fine. The only problem is with this image

Comment: did you have this code in your node expressjs server file: app.use(express.static('app')); instead of "app", use your folder which has your static content

Comment: Yes.  I have the location of my image in place of "app"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me only when I transfered my image to the same location as my node js file, nothing else worked though it should have.

Answer (score 0):

If your image on same location with your page / same folder and spell image name correctly then try the below code:

```
body {
   background-image: url("3011483-euro2016-omb-pes2016_1.jpg");
}
```

you just need to remove forward slash from the start of filename...

I hope this will help you...

Thanks...

Comment: I am getting the error only when I use node js, otherwise it has started woring fine. I have edited my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your **HTML FILE and IMAGE** are in the same folder then

```
 background-image: url("YOUR-IMAGE-NAME");
```

Other than if you create any folder

> --FOLDER/YOUR-IMAGE-IMAGE
>
> -HTML file

code would be like this.

```
 background-image: url("FOLDER/YOUR-IMAGE-NAME");
```

The Alternate method you can use this with your full PATH starting with `file:///`.

```
file:///C:/imagename
```

I HOPE THIS ANSWER HELPS YOU.

Comment: Hi, they are working fine directly, but not through node js

Comment: @SuchitraIyer It seems your node js server is not loading all the static files, i.e. the server doesn't read the image, but just the html. Change the way you are running your node server.

Comment: @SuchitraIyer try `base` tag in `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

Put your image into a folder, and then type the path and see
like

```
body {
  background-image: url("images/loading.jpg");
},
```

since you are using node.js, this thread might help you

[How to serve the image files using express framework in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15379004/how-to-serve-the-image-files-using-express-framework-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  background-image: url("../../loadingimage.jpg");
},
```

Comment: i think your image path should  resolved from server root location

Comment: currently my server is my machine only, My node js express is running on my PC only

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: Thanks  @abarisone for suggestions, I will do it.